# how to override css in Vue component

Tags: css, vue.js

I have drop-down in vue component and class of that element is "form-control" and it has it's own styles. I need to override the styles of that class. for that I have done coding as follows (in vue component),

```
<style scoped>
.form-control{
  border-radius: 50px !important;
  color: #823F98 !important;
  border: 1px solid #3FA294 !important;
}
</style>
```

but this one didn't work for me. so, how to override it?

Thank you!

Comment: Your vue component has the other vue component inside? If that's the case, "scoped" styles [_will not leak into child components_](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#child-component-root-elements).

Comment: yeah. the dropdown is another vue component and I am using that component in another vue component. so, is there any way to ovrride the styles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using unscoped style can be very dangerous especially general class names like `form-control`.

I think it's a better way to use deep styles in your parent component:

```
<style scoped>
>>>.form-control{
  border-radius: 50px !important;
  color: #823F98 !important;
  border: 1px solid #3FA294 !important;
}
</style>
```

but if you can refactor your child component and add a props like `formControlStyle` with your CSS styles would be the best solution to avoid side effects. You can add a default value to this prop that is your styles in your child component.

Answer (score 3):

You should remove scoped. If you leave scoped it will not apply on other components including those you import.

Or move that css in app.css or app.scss.

Comment: I have tried removing the scoped and it works for me. is it affect other parts of the project??

Comment: It affects all elements using that .form-control class

Answer (score 1):

Use Deep Selector, ie, `:deep(.whatever-style-name)` you want to override in your current component

```
<style scoped>
:deep(.form-control) {
  border-radius: 50px;
  color: #823F98;
  border: 1px solid #3FA294;
}
</style>
```

by doing this, you can remove the need to use '!important' in every line of css codes that needs overiding.

Refer [here](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-css-features.html#scoped-css) in the Vue official docs for more info.